# Unclogging sink drain with plastic pipe using snake

Tags: drain, sink, clog

I am interested in a snake tool for unclogging pipes, but I want to be able to use it for a sink that does not have steel drain pipe but plastic.
Is a snake safe to use for such pipes? Or what would be the best tool?

Comment: Can you [edit](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/245152/edit) your post and add a picture?

Answer (score 3):

It should be fine. If you're talking about plastic pipes directly under the sink (like in the picture below) it's usually easier and more efficient to remove them before trying to snake the drain pipe located in the wall.

[image: how-to-clear-clogged-sink-drains/]https://www.familyhandyman.com/project/how-to-clear-clogged-sink-drains/

In general the snake is best used on the pipes that are not accessible while the pipes you can get to directly are usually removed and unclogged by hand.

The most likely spot for a clog is in the "P-Trap" which can be accessed by loosening the compression fittings before and after the trap. *Don't forget to put a bucket under it.* If that's not where the clog is (and that's pretty common) loosen the fitting where the trap arm goes into the wall and introduce the snake there.

Feed as much of the snake in as you can until you hit an obstruction. Then turn the snake slowly clockwise until it gets past the obstruction. Continue feeding the snake into the pipe and turning the snake to encourage the snake to continue along the pipe. Once you get through the clog (or run out of snake) reverse the process to get the snake back out.

It can be dirty work, but other than crawling under the sink, it isn't difficult.

Comment: This is the kind of material for the pipe but in my case that trap arm in the picture does not go in the wall but goes down the floor and I can't access that part

Comment: Where the arm goes isn't particularly important as long as you can disassemble the trap.

Comment: Actually I can not. I goes directly to the floor without a way to remove/disassemble it

Answer (score 2):

I would start with one of these (Drain hair puller).   It is a cheap little miracle.

[image]

Comment: These are great, especially for bathroom sinks. They will just get into the trap, though, so they won't clean beyond that if the clog isn't there. As mentioned, it's a great place to _start_.